# Issues with StellarGraph's Unsupervised GraphSage Example

Tags: python-3.x, keras, graph, stellargraph

I attempted to run the "graphsage-unsupervised-sampler-embeddings.ipynb" notebook (you can find it here ([link](https://colab.research.google.com/github/stellargraph/stellargraph/blob/master/demos/embeddings/graphsage-unsupervised-sampler-embeddings.ipynb))), but I encountered an error at the following line of code:

`node_embeddings = embedding_model.predict(node_gen, workers=4, verbose=1)`

The error message I received is as follows:

`ValueError: in user code:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 2341, in predict_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 2327, in step_function  **
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 2315, in run_step  **
    outputs = model.predict_step(data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 2283, in predict_step
    return self(x, training=False)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/input_spec.py", line 219, in assert_input_compatibility
    raise ValueError(

ValueError: Layer "model_9" expects 3 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, None, None) dtype=float32>]
```

`

I would appreciate any assistance in identifying the reason for this error and finding a solution.

Tried to even run this code [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58549321/creating-embeddings-using-stellargraph-are-not-reproducible). However, I am still encountering the same error.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: ran in the same error. Did you solve it?